# azure batch network_configuration -> "failed to authenticate"

Tags: python, azure, azure-batch

I am using the Azure batch service for calculations on ubuntu nodes, and it works fine. Recently I wanted to change the nodes to be on the same subnet, so I will have the possibility to use mpi in the future as well as use NFS for file acces to a common files server also on azure.

But after adding:

```
network_configuration = batchmodels.NetworkConfiguration(subnet_id=subnet.id)
```

to my batchmodels.PoolAddParameter I suddenly receive:

> {'value': 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the
>   value of Authorization header is formed
>   correctly.\nRequestId:a815194a-8a66-4cb4-847e-60db4ca3ff10\nTime:2017-10-23T15:04:00.3938448Z',
>   'lang': 'en-US'}

Any ideas to why? Without the network_configuration my pool starts fine...

Comment: Are you using Batch Service pool allocation mode (i.e., not User Subscription)?

Comment: Not sure wat you mean. I use azure.batch.batch_service_client and basically have build my script according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-python-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

finally got it to work...

I needed to have the same credentials (and then again not fully) for the two clients in use here. Also I needed to activate batch in the app I have to set up to get credentials... I ended with something like this:

```
def get_credentials(res):
    if res=='mgmt':
        r='https://management.core.windows.net/'
    elif res=='batch':
        r="https://batch.core.windows.net/"

    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = id,
        secret = secret,
        tenant = tenant,
        resource = r
    )
    return credentials
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(get_credentials('mgmt'), sub_id)
batch_client = batch.BatchServiceClient( get_credentials('batch'), base_url=batchserviceurl)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [Azure Active Directory](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/batch.html#azure-active-directory-authentication) for authenticating with the Batch Service to enable `NetworkConfiguration` on a pool with Batch Service pool allocation mode accounts (which are the default).